# Updating Core Data entity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, entity

How do I update Core Data entities, what actions are needed? I have a `Store`with one-to-many relationship to `Product`. When I do a change to the products, remove one or add, do I need to do anything then such as invoking some methods? Or do I just edit products and leave them alone and then they are saved to persistent store when the user quits the application? Is that the normal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save them to be persistant - see [Managed Object Context in the Core Data Programming Guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-SW3):

> Unless you actually save those changes, however, the persistent store remains unaltered.

so here is the code

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL savedSuccessfully = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
if (!savedSuccessfully) {
    NSLog(@"Could not save date change! Reason : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

You should save often and not only when exiting the app. See this answer: [How often should I save to Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085170/1059709)

> When I do a change to the products, remove one or add, do I need to do anything then such as invoking some methods?

This depends on the delete rule you set in the entity in the core data model.

- nullify: any other object in the relationshipto the deleted object will have those relationship set to nil. for to-many relationships the delted object will just be removed from the collection.
- cascade: any other object with a relationship to the object is deleted too.
- deny: the delete will ne denied if there are any other related objects.
- no action: any other object with a relation to the object will be left unchanged.

Comment: Only partly answers all my questions

Comment: So you need to invoke `save` at the context object each time you do a change? You don't rely on the save context that happens when the user close the app.

Comment: But that code is already added in the app delegate. Is it normal to spread the save context around in the app?

Comment: It is normal to save context in different parts of the application whenever user has completed a step or task.